# Mysqlimport.exe from a remote windows computer into Centos Remote server

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I have a number of batch files running on my Windows pc via scheduled task. At the moment i am uploading the data to my live server using the following command:

mysqlimport.exe --host=(remoteip) --user=root --password=password --local --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-optionally-enclosed-by="\"" --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --ignore-lines=1 dbname U:\CSV-Replaced-Output\tablename.csv

Can you tell me if this is the most secure way of uploading lots of data automatically? Also the csv files can be upto 150mb is there anytime of compression i could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add --compress to compress the traffic.

more information here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_compress

Not sure about the security of the transaction.